# Network Brother scanner: change default scan destination

Tags: networking, hard-drive, scanner

I hooked myself up with a Brother MFC-J840DW. I got the wireless print and scan functions to work: when I start a scan from my computer (using simple scan) I can save the scan only on the same HDD as my Ubuntu 14.04 is installe on. I want to be able to save to an additional HDD. How do I do this?
Also, when I start a scan from the scanner directly, the scan is by default saved in /home/MYNAME/brscan. Again I would like to change the destination to be on the other HDD. Any ideas?
Cheers

Comment: Instead of just using `simple-scan`, do `cd The_Other_Place;simple-scan`. If you need more control, consider using `sane` (`Scanner Access Now Easy: API for accessing scanners`). Begin with `man sane`